# Apache VirtualDocumentRoot statement

Tags: apache, http, virtualhost

I have the following setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/oliver/Sites/domains/%-2+/public
</VirtualHost>
```

The example of **testing.com.dev** would point to: /var/www/html/domains/**testing.com**.

I want to make it so that, instead, **dev.testing.com** would point to: /var/www/html/domains/**testing.com**

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might have already figured this out, but here is the solution for you:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/oliver/Sites/domains/%2+/public
</VirtualHost>
```

I just replaced "%-2+" in your code with "%2+". Replace your existing code with this one and restart Apache.